# Why am I not getting a notification from the Vodapay backend when a payment is completed?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I provided the Vodapay backend with an endpoint to send a notification to when a payment is completed (paymentNotifyUrl), however, I am not receiving anything from Vodapay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a payment succeeds, the Vodapay backend sends you a notification immediately.

If the payment goes into one of these 3 states

1. Processing  (my.tradePay returns status 8000)
2. User cancelled (my.tradePay returns status 6001)
3. Payment failed (my.tradePay returns 4000)

The attribute **"paymentExpiryTime"** in the payload you send to the **payments/pay** endpoint determines how long it will take for the Vodapay backend to send a notification to your endpoint.
If the payment enters one of the 3 states above, you can allow the user to retry the payment using the same **"redirecturl"**, as long as the time you had set in **"paymentExpiryTime"** has not arrived.

The default time period for **"paymentExpiryTime"** is 7 days from the time of the payment. If based on your business requirements, this is too long a period, then you can set it to a shorter time frame eg. a date/time 30mins into the future.